# Android after clicking on listview item, open new activity and set text there, text does't change

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to create simple app in Android Studio.
Basically listview of some bigger towns, after clicking on any I would like to create an activity and based on which item was clicked, I'd like to set text of textview of new activity on some basic text like "One", or town description e.g.
The problem is setting text, it simply doesn't work and I can't really figure out why.
The id passed to t(Textview) is the id from new Acticity (its textview)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), newActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTV);
            if (i == 0) {
                t.setText("Zero");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                t.setText("One");
            } else if (i == 2) {
                t.setText("Two");
            } else if (i == 3) {
                t.setText("Three");
            }  else {
                t.setText("...");
            }
        }
    };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            String[] m = {"Rome", "Florence", "Paris", "Edinburgh",
                    "London", "Prague", "Venice", "Brisbane", "Kyoto", "Rio de Janeiro"};
            ArrayList<String> towns = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(m));
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.element, towns);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
    
            list.setOnItemClickListener(myClick);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the TextView is not showing any text in the target Activity (`newActivity.class`) is because the text data to be shown in the TextView has to be passed from the exiting Activity (`MainActivity`) using a [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle) object to the Intent that starts the `NewActivity`.

I would assume that variable 't' is supposed to be the TextView of `newActivity.class` and not `MainActivity`.

That would mean you would have to move it's initialization code to the `onCreate()` of `NewActivity`.

It should not be in the `onItemClick()` of the `MainActivity`.

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

The next step you would want to take is to create a `Bundle` object in the `onItemClick()` and pass the relevant text information to the target Activity. This is one way to do so:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), newActivity.class);
        Bundle txtBundle = new Bundle();
        
        if (i == 0) {
            txtBundle.putString("text", "Zero");
        } else if (i == 1) {
            txtBundle.putString("text", "One");
        } else if (i == 2) {
            txtBundle.putString("text", "Two");
        } else if (i == 3) {
            txtBundle.putString("text", "Three");
        }  else {
            txtBundle.putString("text", "...");
        }

       intent.putExtras(txtBundle);

       startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then proceed to the `onCreate()` of the `NewActivity` and retrieve the Bundle that was added to the Intent that started it like so:

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_activity_layout);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTV);
        Bundle txtBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String text = txtBundle.getString("text");
        t.setText(text);   
 
}
```

Hopefully this should solve the problem.

Comment: The line: "Bundle txtBundle = getExtras();" does't work tbh, I guess u meant "getIntent().getExtras();", am I correct? I've changed it to "getIntent().getExtras();" and it runs correctly now, thanks a lot